# Coefplot fit next to each other

Tags: stata, coefplot

I am creating three coefficient plots with the same variables and want them to be one next to each other, but the third one does not fit horizontally so it appears under the other two. My code is

```
coefplot reg1O reg2O, bylabel(Overall) || reg1R reg2R, bylabel(Right) || reg1L reg2L, bylabel(Left) ||, keep(xvar1 xvar2 xvar3) xline(0, lpattern(dash)) nokey ciopts(lcolor(blue) recast(rcap)) color(blue)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to tell Stata to expand the eps figure horizontally so that all plots fit next to each other, regardless of how much space it takes?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably not because of lack of space, but rather because you don't specify the option `byopts(compact rows(1))`. If you want all pots on one row or one column, you need to specify that. It's hard to tell without a reproducible example, though.

You probably know this webpage, but it's also explained here, in the section "How subgraphs are combined": http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/coefplot/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi cremorna, using your command, is there a way to tell stata to leave a small space between the plots? At the moment they are touching each other with vertical lines dividing them. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, just remove the word "compact".